# Python powering of 0 giving weird results

Tags: python-3.5

Not sure why but when using the power operator I get:

```
-50 ** 0
```

*Result:*

```
-1
```

Which is expected but:

```
(50 - 100) ** 0
```

*Result:*

```
1
```

Using Python 3.5.2

Comment: When you do -50**0 it evaluates as -(50)**0 so you end up with -(1), or -1.  The one with (50 - 100) works because it is (-1)**0 = 1.  The exponentiation has a higher precedence than the minus/subtraction sign. Check out Section 6.16 on order precedence https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html

Comment: Oh, dang I see. Thought it might be a good way to reduce the +-1, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precedence is different for the two equations, hence the bracketed equation gives the actual result:

```
(-50) ** 0
```

*Result:*

```
1
```

Cheers: [Noah Christopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7159238/noah-christopher)